# Order relation and union

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

My question may seem a bit strange, but I asked it anyway.

Suppose two orders sets. $A$ and $B$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Is $A\cup B$ an order set?

A concrete case : suppose $A=\{0,1\}$ with the order $0<1$   and $B=\{2,3\}$ with $3<2$. Is $A\cup B$ an order set?

If i want $A\cup B$ to be an order set systematically what condition do I have to apply on $A$ and $B$

Thank you

Comment: You have to check three properties (I suppose you know which are they) for the union relation in the union of those sets. What have you tried, if anything?

Comment: The question is kind of pointless if you do not specify a purported order relation on $A\cup B$, or at least some axiomatic properties that said relation must satisfy, at which point the question becomes: given $(A,\le)$ and $(B,\preceq)$ such that $A\cap B=\varnothing$, is there an order relation $R$ on $A\cup B$ such that yad yada yada ?